# Posting many input relational values - jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a form which users could add input to it. so they could add as many inputs they want.
Each time they click on "Add New" button, this happens:

```
$('#add_specification').on('click', function(){
        var new_item = '<input type="text" class="specification_title" title="TITLE" /> : <input type="text" class="specification_desc" title="DESCRIPTION" /> ';
        $('#specifications_inputs_holder').append(new_item);
    });
```

As you see in the code above, on each click 2 new input will add to the form, the first one is for the title and the second one is for the description, now imagine the user has clicked on the "Add New" button 3 times, so we have 6 input boxes:

[image]

Now I want to submit the form, I want that the whole value could be sent like:

```
var specifications = ('Title 1=>Description 1','Title 2=>Description 2','Title 3=>Description 3');
```

So in the serve side I could still see the related data to each other, how I could achieve this?

What I think I should do is using jQuery each() and an array:

```
$('#specifications_inputs_holder input').each(function(count){
    specifications[count] = $(this).val();
});
```

But this doesn't sound a good solution, anybody could help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop to get all the key/value pairs via XML and push them to an array:

```
var $title = $('.specification_title'),
    $desc =- $('.specification_desc'),
    arr = [];

for(var i=0;i<$title.length;i++){
    var key = $title.eq(i).val(),
        val = $desc.eq(i).val(),
        pair = {key:val};
    arr.push(pair);
}
```

Now you have an array looking like:

```
[{title1:desc1},{title2:desc2},...,{titleX:descX}]
```

That way on the PHP side you can just use the keys as inputted.

Comment: still need to wait 34 seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery :

```
var spec = [];
$('.specification_title').each(function() {
  var index = $(this).attr('data-index');

  $(spec).push({$(this).val():$('.specification_desc[data-index='+index).val()});

});
```

And in your adding item function :

```
var new_item = '<input type="text" data-index='+parseint($('.specification_title').length+1)+' class="specification_title" title="TITLE" /> : <input type="text" data-index='+parseint($('.specification_title').length+1)+' class="specification_desc" title="DESCRIPTION" /> ';
```

This will work (for data-index) if you can only delete the last item. Otherwise, use an incremential global var instead.

[EDIT]

And what about change the input name to be sync with the content, to retrieve good array... To be faster!

```
$('input[class^="specification"').change(function() {
  $(this).attr('name', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: they are inputs, the users are gonna update their values, Title and Description was just for example there so you understand they are connected to each other!